# Does $〈Ax,y⟩=〈x,A^*y⟩$ hold for any inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $\Bbb C^n$. Let $A^*$ be the conjugate transpose of matrix $A$, I see in many materials $A^*$ is also called the adjoint of $A$. I am now confused by that does $〈Ax,y⟩=〈x,A^*y⟩$ hold just for the standard inner product (whose proof is simple), or any inner product? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not hold for every inner product. The analogous situation in the real plane illustrates this. Consider
$$
H = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}
$$
and the inner product $x \cdot y = x^t H y$. 
Let 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}
$$
$x =  \pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $y =  \pmatrix{0\\1}$.

Then $Ax \cdot y = 1$, but $x \cdot A^t y = 2$.

Since the real plane is a subspace of the complex plane, this suffices as a counterexample in $\Bbb C^2$ as well (at least if you extend the definition of the dot product by writing $x \cdot y = x^t H \bar{y}$).

Comment: With the right commutativity condition on $H$ and $A$, _then_ $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle$.

Comment: your definition doesn't hold in $\mathbb C^2$ for conjugate symmetry, e.g., consider $x=[i, 1]^T, y=[1, i]^T$, then $ <x, y>=3i= <y, x>$, but the later one should be $-3i$.

Comment: alex.jordan: yes. I was hoping that OP might discover that by working through the definitions. @novavita: it's true. You have to properly generalize my definition of "dot" by writing $x \cdot y = x^t H \bar{y}$. I should probably have mentioned this in my last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the answer is no, and depends on the structure of the inner product. More specifically, it requires that the orthogonal basis under the inner product is a unitary matrix.

Let's clarify some notations first. Denote by $T$ the operator transforming $x$ to $Ax$. Then $T$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb C^n$ to itself, i.e., $T\in \mathcal L (\mathbb C^n)$, we prefer to use $T^*$ as the "adjoint" operator defined by the equation:
$$
<Tx, y>=<x, T^* y>
$$
for any $x, y \in \mathbb C^n$.

Consider an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb C^n$, $\tilde e=(\tilde e_1, \tilde e_2,...,\tilde e_n)$ under inner product $<.,.>$. Then the matrix of $T$ under this basis is $[m_{ij}]_{n\times n}$, where $m_{ij}=<T\tilde e_j,\tilde e_i>$, which we denoted as $M(T,\tilde e)$.

On the other hand, since
$$
T(x)=Ax
$$
Then the matrix of $T$ under the trivial basis $e=(e_1, e_2,...,e_n)$ where $e_1=[1,0,...,0]^T$, $e_2=[0,1,...,0]^T$,..., i.e., $M(T, e)=A$.
We use $A^H$ to denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Then we can show the matrix of the linear operator $T^*$ under basis $\tilde e$ (well, we need to prove it's linear first, which is not very hard) is the conjugate transpose of $M(T,\tilde e)$, i.e.,
$$
 M(T^*,\tilde e)=M(T,\tilde e)^H\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
Now change the basis from $\tilde e$ to $e$, we get
$$
\tilde e^{-1} M(T^*,e) \tilde e= (\tilde e^{-1} A \tilde e)^H=(\tilde e)^H A^H (\tilde e^{-1})^H
$$
If we want $M(T^*,e)=A^H$ holds for all $A$, then
$$
\tilde e^{-1} A^H \tilde e=(\tilde e)^H A^H (\tilde e^{-1})^H
$$
which requires $\tilde e$ being a unitary matrix:
$$
(\tilde e)^H \tilde e = I_n
$$

---

To see why (1) holds, consider the $j^{th}$ column of $M \equiv M(T,\tilde e)$, call it $M_j$. It's obvious that
$$
M_j=M\tilde e_j
$$
on the other hand,
$$
M\tilde e_j=T\tilde e_j=<T\tilde e_j,\tilde e_1>\tilde e_1+<T\tilde e_j,\tilde e_2>\tilde e_2+...+<Te_j,\tilde e_n>\tilde e_n
$$
so $m_{ij}=<T\tilde e_j,\tilde e_i>$

Similarly, let $M^* \equiv M(T^*,\tilde e)$, then 
$$
m^*_{ji}=<T^* \tilde e_i,\tilde e_j>=< \tilde e_i,(T^*)^*\tilde e_j>=< \tilde e_i,T\tilde e_j>= \overline {< T\tilde e_i,\tilde e_j>}
$$
this holds for each $(i,j)$, which means $M^*=M^H$

Comment: Is this level 1 linear algebra? I guess this is advanced algebra or something? Can you refer a book for me to understand what you wrote?

Answer (score -2):

$〈Ax,y⟩=〈x,A^*y⟩ $ this holds for any inner product ! when you assume $A^*$ is adjoint of $A$ in space X equipped with inner product of $〈.,.⟩$

This is how adjoint operators  defined in finite dimension.

Comment: Hey Down voter(s): never vote down bcz of your lack of knowledge  !

Comment: I think the downvotes are because the question states specifically that $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix $A$.

Comment: @littleO  I was just trying to convey a message  to OP that what he has seen in many material is correct ... but his/her interpretation of  adjoint as simple transpose is not always true !  adjoint = transpose if  one works with Euclidean inner product ...   

And I bet those who down vote thinks adjoint is same as transpose ...

Comment: In general, if you want to convey a message, it's best to convey that message, rather than to redefine the notation explicitly defined in the question. You had a good point to make, and a slight rewriting would probably get folks to remove their downvotes. As for "I bet those downvoters are idiots,"... well...that's your choice, but a lot of experience with the folks who tend to read multiple answers and think about their quality here suggests otherwise, at least to me.

Comment: @JohnHughes  I believe I didn't redefine anything. Notice that  I used the word  "WHEN  you assume ..."  since the notation $A^*$ generally refers to adjoint  which in the particular case ,the dot product,  the notation $\bar{A^T}$ is used for conjugate transpose. And I thought that's the where confusion come from. I posted my answer after you, so I already read yours and voted it up, but I felt still confusion exists or maybe your answer make it worse! then I posted this answer. BTW Someone who plays with words it is you not me! I never used the word "idiots".

Comment: I was paraphrasing, and I should not have. What you said was that it was because of their "lack of knowledge", and that's what I really doubted anyhow. English appears to not be your first language, and you did far better in it than I could do in any of my non-first languages. You should by all means continue to believe that you answered perfectly, and ignore suggestions like mine. The "market" will decide.