# What math to take after Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In Linear Algebra class we're covering Vector Spaces and it's the most fascinating thing that I've ever seen in mathematics class. I'll be majoring in Actuarial Science and I was hoping to take something abstract, what could I take? I would like to understand how to write proofs, and above all, see something that isn't calculus. I'm not at the university yet and the highest math offered is the one I'm taking at the moment. I'll be transferring after the summer.

I was hoping to take two classes that don't have to directly contribute to my major. I would consider them as a fun classes that I would do serious work.

Comment: Are you going to study mathematics for your own interest or for application in actuarial science and statistics?

Comment: These two classes don't have to be related to actuarial science. I want to take them for my personal interest.

Comment: Do you mean by linear algebra that that covers up to eigenvalues and eigenvectors? I saw some answers about linear algebra which sounds very complex to me and were not covered in David C Lay book for example like the one in this answer of vita nova: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458301/does-ax-y-x-ay-hold-for-any-inner-product

Answer (score 2):

If you like vector spaces and such, you'll probably like abstract algebra more broadly. An undergraduate class will cover group theory and may go further than that depending on the curriculum. You'll also be exposed to proof writing in earnest. Maybe look into rings, fields, modules and algebras over fields on your own time.

Moving away from algebra, you might try a course in topology or geometry, though the latter would likely involve calculus. The former might be a refreshing departure from your prior math education and would also sharpen your proof writing. Intersecting the two fields, you might try to find an introductory course in Lie theory, the study of Lie groups and Lie algebras.

Speaking to Tony's answer, it might be that your institution lists real analysis as a prerequisite to topology, though I find that logic to be sort of backwards as the former is a special case of the latter.

Comment: I second abstract algebra. You'll learn how vector spaces fit into the theory of more general algebraic structures, and if you found vector spaces to be fascinating I would imagine this would also be very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Take Dynamical System, you won't regret it! One of my favourite math classes in college.

Answer (score 0):

Most maths programs would have you next take real analysis (called fundamentals of analysis 1 at my university). You will study proofs, and more abstract maths. I would also recommend number theory.

Comment: Do you mean by linear algebra that that covers up to eigenvalues and eigenvectors? I saw some answers about linear algebra which sounds very complex to me and were not covered in David C Lay book for example like the one in this answer of vita nova: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458301/does-ax-y-x-ay-hold-for-any-inner-product